# LINQ OrderBy for complex entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have complex query:

```
var containers = this.Repository.Containers
                .Include(x => x.PostsContainers)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Post)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.TasksPosts)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Task)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.AssignedToUser);

var items = containers.Where(x => x.PostsContainers
                              .Any(y => y.Post.TasksPosts
                                  .Any(z => z.Task.DateDue <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                                      && !z.Task.Completed
                                      && z.Task.AssignedToUserId.Value == userId)));
```

I got `items` but I also need to sort these items by `Task.DueDate` and extract `AssignedToUser` name.

What's the best way to do it (with good performance, without code duplication)? Maybe I need to rewrite my code?

Comment: Since it seems to be a db query you need to check the actual SQL which is generated by your ORM and validate it's performance and optimize it. Depended on your data may be it can be more performant to even make few requests and/or fetched extra data and handle the business logic on client side(in code) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refactor it this way:

```
  var dateDue = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)

  var result = (from c in this.Repository.Containers
                from pc in c.PostsContainers
                from tp in pc.Post.TasksPosts
                where tp.Task.DateDue <= dateDue
                   && !tp.Task.Completed
                   && tp.Task.AssignedToUserId == userId
                orderby tp.Task.DueDate
                select new
                {
                    Container = c,
                    tp.Task.AssignedToUser
                })
                .ToList();
```